# How to setup MongoDB with username and password

Tags: mongodb, security, nosql

I am setting up MongoDB in Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed it using the commands given on their [page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). After the installation, I have downloaded `NoSqlBooster` and have connected to Mongo server using localhost.

I have created a database named `RIPE` and have also added some collections and test documents. At this point, I have also created some read users for `RIPE` so that I can share read user credentials with my colleagues for them to use it. I do not want them to make changes so just want to give them read access. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

My first question is, I have added `ttread` user in `RIPE` db which we can see in above image but why its showing it outside of `RIPE` db as well?

My second question is, how can I make users to directly connect to `RIPE` db. In nosqlbooster, when I am connecting to localhost, I have mentioned `AuthDB` as `RIPE` as shown below:

[image]

[image]

and when it connects it shows other db as well like, `admin`, `config`, `local`.

Last question, while setting up MongoDB how can I add a username and password because any user can connect to localhost without username and password. So what is the best way to setup security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable authentication do following steps:

1. Change your configuration file and enable authentication:

   ```
   security:
     authorization: enabled
   ```
2. Restart your MongoDB, typically `systemctl restart mongod`
3. Create the user administrator

   ```
   db.getSiblingDB("admin").createUser({
      user: "root",
      pwd: passwordPrompt(), // or cleartext password
      roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
   })
   ```

Unless the user administrator is created you can still connect to your MongoDB without username/password, this behavior is called [Localhost Exception](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/localhost-exception/#localhost-exception)

Personally I don't see any reason to create users in other database than `admin`, see [What is the "admin" database in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253839/what-is-the-admin-database-in-mongodb).

I would create the user like this:

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand( {
   createUser: "ttread",
   pwd: passwordPrompt(),
   roles: [ { role: "read", db: "RIPE " } ]
} )
```