# String connection for mongoDB using mongoose with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Do you why i can't log in with a connetion string like this:
`mongodb://root:*****@localhost:27017/Database`
But, i can log in with a one like this:
`mongodb://root:*****@localhost:27017/`
I had an "authentication failed"

Also, i can log in like that:
`mongodb://root:*****@localhost:27017/admin`

I don't know where i can looking for a solution.

Thank you for your help

I've tried with a database with a name in lowercase but nothing works.

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB uses admin DB for [authentication and authorization purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253839/what-is-the-admin-database-in-mongodb).

From official [MongoDB document on Connection URI](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/),

> If specified, the client will attempt to authenticate the user to the
> `authSource`. If `authSource` is unspecified, the client will attempt to authenticate the user to the `defaultauthdb`. And if the `defaultauthdb` is unspecified, to the admin database.

As you are providing `username:password@`, you are implying the usage of `defaultauthdb`.

- `mongodb://root:*****@localhost:27017/admin` works because you specified `admin` as the `defaultauthdb`
- `mongodb://root:*****@localhost:27017/` works because `defaultauthdb` is unspecified. So it is referred to the admin database

`mongodb://root:*****@localhost:27017/Database` does not work because you are using database other than admin db to perform the auth.